# Custom Powershell Nested Class not Found

Tags: powershell, class, module

I've got 3 files with custom PS classes.

```
NestedClass.psm1
ChildClass.psm1
ParentClass.psm1
```

Inside ParentClass I've got the following code:
`using Module ".\ChildClass.psm1"`

And I can see the classes inside ChildClass.

Inside ChildClass I've got the following code:
`using Module ".\NestedClass.psm1"`

And I can see what's inside NestedClass from inside ChildClass.
The problem is I can't see any Nested classes from the Parent class file.

I've tried a number of things including manifest files where I define:
`RequiredModules = @('NestedClass.psd1')`
and
`ScriptsToProcess = @('NestedClass.ps1')`
and
`NestedModules = @('NestedClass.psd1')`

No matter what I do I can't seem to get the nested classes to be seen in the parent class file.

What am I doing wrong?